# how to send push notification in iphone using java

Tags: java, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to send `push` notification to iphone using `java`. For this I cam across this library called `relayrides pushy`. But I am new to this `APNS` thing.

**What I want to do**
I want to send simple message like 'hello world' to iphone as a notification.

**What I have**
I have one, `Certificates.p12` file with password. I also have device token and gcn ID.

can any one show me some sample code of connecting and sending `push` notification using `pushy`. Which maven dependency should I include?, because every time I am visiting some site, I am getting errors like `SimpleApnsPushNotification` class not found in library or `PushManager` class is not found. And also what has SLF4J has to do with sending notifications, please provide me some relevant code snippets for handling these issues, because I am totally messed up.

Comment: down voters please note that there is neither much resource available for this on stackoverflow and nor while googling any other site.

Answer (score 0):

Just to try and help you along a little, I'm going to include some code that implements pushy.  The `send()` method takes in a token String (the device appId), a String value of the text you wish to send, and a custom property you may want to send along (only included as an example for you).  I really hope this helps you out.

```
public class PushNotificationManager {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(PushNotificationManager.class);
    private static final Object SINGLETON_LOCK = new Object();
    private static final Object PUSH_MANAGER_LOCK = new Object();
    private static PushNotificationManager singleton;
    private final SSLContext ssl;
    private PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification> pushManager;

    private PushNotificationManager() throws UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, IOException {
        File certificateFile = new File(PropertyUtil.getInstance().get("apns", "file"));
        ssl = SSLContextUtil.createDefaultSSLContext(certificateFile.getAbsolutePath(), "yourCertPassword");
    }

    private PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification> getPushManager() {
        if (pushManager == null || pushManager.isShutDown()) {
            synchronized (PUSH_MANAGER_LOCK) {
                if (pushManager == null || pushManager.isShutDown()) {
                    ApnsEnvironment apnsEnviroment = ApnsEnvironment.getSandboxEnvironment();
                    PushManagerConfiguration config = new PushManagerConfiguration();
                    ApnsConnectionConfiguration connectionConfiguration = new ApnsConnectionConfiguration();
                    config.setConnectionConfiguration(connectionConfiguration);
                    PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification> newPushManager = new PushManager<SimpleApnsPushNotification>(apnsEnviroment, ssl, null, null, null, config, "ExamplePushManager");
                    newPushManager.start();
                    pushManager = newPushManager;
                }
            }
        }
        return pushManager;
    }

    public static PushNotificationManager getInstance() {
        if (singleton == null) {
            synchronized (SINGLETON_LOCK) {
                if (singleton == null) {
                    try {
                        singleton = new PushNotificationManager();
                    } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | IOException e) {
                        log.error("Error loading key.", e);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    public void send(String tokenString, String text, String customProperty) throws MalformedTokenStringException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            final byte[] token = TokenUtil.tokenStringToByteArray(tokenString);
            final ApnsPayloadBuilder payloadBuilder = new ApnsPayloadBuilder();
            payloadBuilder.setAlertBody(text);
            payloadBuilder.addCustomProperty("customProperty", customProperty);
            getPushManager().getQueue().put(new SimpleApnsPushNotification(token, payloadBuilder.buildWithDefaultMaximumLength()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            pushManager = null;
            throw e;
        }
    }
```